# Sending email in Azure Webjob using Google SMTP

Tags: c#, azure, smtpclient, azure-webjobs

I have written a simple console app to sent a test email from Azure using WebJobs however while the Job says it has run successfully the email never arrives. The app works fine when run locally.

here is the code:

```
    static void SendMail()
    {

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mygmail@gmail.com", "*********")
        };

        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("toemail@jaddress.net.nz");
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("fromemail@jaddress.net.nz");
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

        mail.Subject = "Test Email";

        mail.Body =
            ("This is a test @\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
        smtp.Send(mail);

        Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to debug in Azure so at a loss to find out what is happening.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Comment: Are you using the [Webjobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk)?

Comment: No, just a console app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webjobs look for a Main function signature as an entry point by default. It's like your regular Console Aplication. If you put any `Console.Write` lines, it will output too.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //your code...
    }
}
```

Go to your **WebApp blade** > **All Settings** and scroll down, you should have a **Webjobs** item with your Webjob loaded, now double click on the link on the LOGS column:

[image]

Now, you should be able to Toggle Output and see the Console output of your webjob.

[image]

If there are any errors during execution, they should be there.

If you **can't get see the LOGS link**, try opening the Tools section in the WebApp (top toolbar), scrolling to **Kudu** and Opening it.

[image]

Then go to the Tools > **Webjobs Dashboard**. Your job should be listed there.

[image]

**EDIT**

After seeing the error reported, the problem is that the Azure environment is different than your computer. Google might be blocking the usage based on the access from an unknown origin. Check your [Less secure settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and try it with Off. If that fails, enable login in [from a different timezone](https://g.co/allowaccess). Though I'd advice to use another services to send mail, like [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/windowsazure.html), even [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Comment: Hi, my app does have a Main functions with calls the Send Mail function.

Comment: Sorry, since I didn't see it in your code, I didn't know. If you don't put it, it doesn't trigger any code. Do you see the Console lines on the Output?

Comment: That's the thing I can't see any output. I go to the webjob on the portal and run it, then the message pops up to say its successfully completed.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer so you can see where you can check the output

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go and report back.

Comment: Can find link. see screen shot above.

Comment: Added alternative access

Comment: Thanks. I found the following error: Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. The code worked locally so is there something I need to change for it to work in Azure?

Comment: Thanks, I have the less secure settings turned on for now. The plan will be to use a more secure and robust method I am just trying to prove a concept at this stage. Will try the Timezone setting and report back.

Comment: Success. I needed to allow access from a different timezone. Thank you very much for you help and putting me onto Kudu!

Comment: You're welcome :) Kudu is an awesome debugging tool.